# Qt5/PyQt5 does not recognize mouse buttons 4, 5, 6, 7, but recognizes scrolling

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5

I'm building an application in PyQt5 (5.15.0), Python 3.6, Ubuntu 20.04, where I want to use a Wacom Cintiq 16 tablet with stylus for the user to work with. Using `xsetwacom`([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsetwacom)), one can map the buttons on the stylus. Having mapped one of the buttons to `pan`([explained here](https://www.mankier.com/1/xsetwacom)), holding that button and moving the stylus down/up/right/left outputs pressing and releasing mouse buttons 4, 5, 6, 7 respectively, as confirmed with `xev`. This is the same as using [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html): `xdotool click 4` (or `5`/`6`/`7`)

This functionality works fine in other applications, like Firefox, Terminal etc. However, the PyQt5 program does not react. I've created a small GUI that just listens to events (I've removed  the ones that were irrelevant and did not fire):

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedWidth(500)
        self.setFixedHeight(500)

    def event(self, event) -> bool:
        print("event", event, event.type())
        return super(MainWindow, self).event(event)

    def tabletEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QTabletEvent) -> None:
        print("tabletEvent ", a0.button(), a0.type(), a0.buttons())
        super(MainWindow, self).tabletEvent(a0)

    def mousePressEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        print("mousePressEvent", a0)
        super(MainWindow, self).mousePressEvent(a0)

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QKeyEvent) -> None:
        print("keyReleaseEvent", a0)
        super(MainWindow, self).keyReleaseEvent(a0)

    def nativeEvent(self, eventType, message):
        print("nativeEvent", eventType, message)
        return super(MainWindow, self).nativeEvent(eventType, message)

    def wheelEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QWheelEvent) -> None:
        print("wheelEvent", a0)
        super(MainWindow, self).wheelEvent(a0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

When panning with the stylus, only `HoverEvent` via `event()` and `NativeEvent xcb_generic_event_t` via `nativeEvent()` are seen. When scrolling the mouse wheel however, `WheelEvent` is seen by `wheelEvent()`. The latter is as expected, but for the former I would expect `MousePressEvent` via `mousePressEvent()`, as happens when left/right/middle clicking on the mouse and even the backward/forward buttons on the side of the mouse, but this does not happen. There is no `MousePressEvent` for mouse button 4, 5, 6 or 7.

How can I capture these mouse button triggers in (Py)Qt5?

Comment: You say that using xsetwacom should get the same effect of using xdotool, but, if it were the case, you should properly get wheel events. Try with `xev`, and see if you get *both* press and release events for the mapped gesture on its window.

Comment: @musicamante, I can confirm that the press and release events happen. The missing thing is indeed the wheel event, which is what Qt5 picks up, not the button 4/5/6/7 press and release events.

Comment: Sorry, now I'm confused, what do you mean by "which is what Qt5 picks up"? You said that you didn't get any event at all, except for the native and hover events.

Comment: Qt5 does fire WheelEvents when scrolling, but not when panning with the stylus. `xev` shows that for both scrolling and panning, mouse buttons 4/5/6/7 are pressed/released. The difference however is in what I see with Qt5. Qt5 picks up scrolling, as wheel events, not as mouse button 4/5/6/7 pressed/released. Panning is not picked up either, as that is only mouse button 4/5/6/7.

Comment: Conceptually speaking, scrolling and panning (horizontal scrolling) are considered by the system as a pair of press/release of 4/5 and 6/7 buttons, respectively, and Qt registers *both* of them as wheel event (not mouse press/release events), the horizontal component is `event.angleDelta().x()`. If you don't get any wheel event for horizontal scrolling then it could be a problem with xsetwacom or the underlying xorg configuration.

Comment: Yes, I came to that conclusion as well. I think it is not fixable within Qt5 with the current setup. Thank you for your time.